# Is JpaRepository's findAll() guaranteed to return a non-null result if an exception isn't thrown?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--) is woefully sparse on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented, see section [Null Handling of Repository Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability) of the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/):

> Repository methods returning collections, collection alternatives,
>   wrappers, and streams are guaranteed never to return `null` but rather
>   the corresponding empty representation. See [“Repository query return
>   types”](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types) for details.

As Spring Data JPA generates the query methods based on naming patterns and `JpaRepository` is only one example of such repositories, it probably didn't make sense to document it in the JavaDoc, but instead they put it in the user documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I'd much rather read it in the javadoc (where it's easy to find from my IDE) than a book, but at least it's there.

Comment: @BillHorvath Keep in mind, it equally applies to a `findAll` method in a custom repository directly extending `Repository`, or a custom method returning `List`: that information can't be provided through JavaDoc of the Spring Data JPA team.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [Package summary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/package-summary.html) of `org.springframework.data.repository` says Non-Null APIS. That means that it is guaranteed to return non-null type of objects from the method.

@NonNullAPI tells that package with this annotation is null-safe and API usage need not look into handling the null-check scenario.

Comment: Please expand your answer with details such as a quote of the contract for `@NotNullApi` and your analysis thereof. As it stands, this answer would become weaker if your link were to become unavailable for any reason.

Comment: Thank you. This is an accurate answer that addresses the question, though I'm not especially impressed with the idea of using package-level annotations in this fashion.